# Why does the audio element abort events when setting src?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am unclear about what exactly happens when setting a `src` on the HTML5 `audio` element, and the spec has not been of much help either.

Concretely, my problem is this:

```
const audio = new Audio()
audio.src = "first.mp3"
audio.onratechange = e => console.log('[RATE CHANGE]', e.target.playbackRate)

audio.playbackRate = 0.5

audio.src = "second.mp3"
audio.src = "third.mp3"
```

Setting `playbackRate` is supposed to fire the `ratechange` event. But in the above example, what happens is  that the event for "0.5" is aborted(?) by setting the `src` - instead we get a `ratechange` for "1", which stems from resetting `playbackRate` to `defaultPlaybackRate`.

What happened to the first `ratechange` event that is supposed to be non-`cancelable`?

Furthermore, this `ratechange` event also does not fire, because setting `src` one more time will eat this event as well. So we end up with imperatively setting `playbackRate` and no `ratechange` event firing at all.

See: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6vx4csn/29/)

I guess I am missing something fundamental about how the JS event system works???

Comment: Have you tried setting the src with setTimeout? JavaScript is single-threaded so all the things you set are done at once so most likely what happens is that the system only sees you setting the src to third.mp3 and handles that.

Comment: Setting the src with a zero setTimeout will preserve the events most of the time, but not always, a setTimeout of >10ms seems to work, but that is rather messy, no?